# How to troubleshoot weird nuget dependency

Tags: .net, nuget

I've built a multi-target Nuget I call "mycompany.XP.Desktop"* that I try include in a legacy WPF (FW 4.7.2) project. The Nuget includes support for netstandard 2.0, which is compatible with FW 4.7.2. But when I add the package nuget fails with this message:

```
Install failed (project: wpfClient_fw472, package: mycompany.XP.Desktop v1.0.0-beta.20) Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 8.0.0-rc.2.23480.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

As I do not reference pre-release packages in general, or the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` package in particular, I assumed it must be a transitive dependency so I ran the `dotnet list package --include-transitive` command, and I got this:

```
Project 'mycompany.XP.Desktop' has the following package references
   [netstandard2.0]: 
   Top-level Package                             Requested   Resolved
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection         7.0.5       7.0.5   
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client         7.0.10      7.0.10  
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting                6.0.0       6.0.0   
   > NETStandard.Library                   (A)   [2.0.3, )   2.0.3   

   Transitive Package                                             Resolved     
   > Azure.Core                                                   1.10.0       
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions             2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core                     2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization                           2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy                    2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions                7.0.10       
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal                   7.0.5        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions             7.0.5        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions                    2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions             2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http                                    2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions                       2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client                 7.0.10       
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common                 7.0.10       
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions                         2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features                           2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions                        2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core                                2.2.5        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions            2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing                                 2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions                    2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core                     7.0.10       
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common                          7.0.10       
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json                  7.0.10       
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities                            2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Core                        1.14.0       
   > Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces                                7.0.0        
   > Microsoft.CSharp                                             4.5.0        
   > Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions                        2.1.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration                           6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions              7.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder                    6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine               6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables      6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions            6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json                      6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets               6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection                     7.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions        7.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel                         2.1.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Features                                7.0.10       
   > Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions              7.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical                  6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing                      6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions                    7.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging                                 7.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions                    7.0.1        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration                   6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console                         6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug                           6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog                        6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource                     6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool                              2.2.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Options                                 7.0.1        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions         6.0.0        
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives                              7.0.0        
   > Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions                         6.25.1       
   > Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens                        6.25.1       
   > Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging                              6.25.1       
   > Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens                               6.25.1       
   > Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers                                   2.2.8        
   > Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms                                  1.1.0        
   > Microsoft.NETCore.Targets                                    1.1.0        
   > Microsoft.Win32.Registry                                     5.0.0        
   > Newtonsoft.Json                                              9.0.1        
   > runtime.native.System                                        4.0.0        
   > System.AppContext                                            4.1.0        
   > System.Buffers                                               4.5.1        
   > System.Collections                                           4.0.11       
   > System.Collections.Immutable                                 5.0.0        
   > System.ComponentModel.Annotations                            5.0.0        
   > System.Diagnostics.Debug                                     4.0.11       
   > System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource                          7.0.0        
   > System.Diagnostics.EventLog                                  6.0.0        
   > System.Diagnostics.Tools                                     4.0.1        
   > System.Dynamic.Runtime                                       4.0.11       
   > System.Formats.Asn1                                          7.0.0        
   > System.Globalization                                         4.0.11       
   > System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt                              6.25.1       
   > System.IO                                                    4.1.0        
   > System.IO.FileSystem                                         4.0.1        
   > System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives                              4.0.1        
   > System.IO.Pipelines                                          7.0.0        
   > System.Linq                                                  4.1.0        
   > System.Linq.Expressions                                      4.1.0        
   > System.Memory                                                4.5.5        
   > System.Memory.Data                                           1.0.1        
   > System.Numerics.Vectors                                      4.5.0        
   > System.ObjectModel                                           4.0.12       
   > System.Reflection                                            4.1.0        
   > System.Reflection.Emit                                       4.0.1        
   > System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration                          4.0.1        
   > System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight                           4.0.1        
   > System.Reflection.Extensions                                 4.0.1        
   > System.Reflection.Primitives                                 4.0.1        
   > System.Reflection.TypeExtensions                             4.1.0        
   > System.Resources.ResourceManager                             4.0.1        
   > System.Runtime                                               4.3.0        
   > System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe                       6.0.0        
   > System.Runtime.Extensions                                    4.1.0        
   > System.Runtime.Handles                                       4.0.1        
   > System.Runtime.InteropServices                               4.1.0        
   > System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation            4.0.0        
   > System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives                      4.1.1        
   > System.Security.AccessControl                                6.0.0        
   > System.Security.Cryptography.Cng                             5.0.0        
   > System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs                            7.0.0        
   > System.Security.Cryptography.Xml                             7.0.1        
   > System.Security.Principal.Windows                            5.0.0        
   > System.Text.Encoding                                         4.3.0        
   > System.Text.Encoding.Extensions                              4.0.11       
   > System.Text.Encodings.Web                                    7.0.0        
   > System.Text.Json                                             7.0.3        
   > System.Text.RegularExpressions                               4.1.0        
   > System.Threading                                             4.0.11       
   > System.Threading.Channels                                    7.0.0        
   > System.Threading.Tasks                                       4.0.11       
   > System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions                            4.5.4        
   > System.Xml.ReaderWriter                                      4.0.11       
   > System.Xml.XDocument                                         4.0.11       
   > mycompany.XP.Auth                                             1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Auth.Abstractions                                1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Auth.TokensAndCredentials                        1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Browsers                                         1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Caching                                          1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Caching.Abstractions                             1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Caching.DataProtection                           1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Common                                           1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Configuration                                    1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.DependencyInjection                              1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Diagnostics                                      1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Documentation                                    1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.DynamicEntities                                  1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Identity                                         1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Logging                                          1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Logging.Abstractions                             1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.OAuth2                                           1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Serialization                                    1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Streaming                                        1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.StringValues                                     1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Web                                              1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Web.Abstractions                                 1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Web.Http                                         1.0.0-beta.19
   > mycompany.XP.Web.Services                                     1.0.0-beta.19
```

My meticulously investigating all of my 36 nuget projects, I found one - `mycompany.XP.Identity` - that transitively depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities`, via a reference to `Microsoft.AspnetCore.Http` (which provides extension method to register `IHttpContextAccessor` service). So, it's fine that it has a dependency to that nuget, but I simply can't understand why nuget resolves it needs to include the very latest release candidate, instead of the 2.2.0 version.

I even tried explicitly include the 2.2.0 verison in the `mycompany.XP.Identity` project, rebuild the nugets, and try again. But the same thing still happens, and nuget still complains it can't include the RC version due to incompatibilty.

Is there some setting somewhere I might have flipped by mistake, that forces nuget to behave like this?

How do I troubeshoot these kinds of Nuget issues?

* The actual name of my company was replaced with 'mycompany'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just Rider misbehaving. I tested adding my Nuget to the project using VS2022 instead and that resolved the proper dependencies - not including any pre-released versions. Might be Rider isn't good at legacy stacks, like FW 4.7.2. I'll file it as a bug to JetBrains.